# New laptop. keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, amd-ryzen

I bought a new Lenovo IdeaPad Pro 16 (16ARX) with Ryzen 6800HS. Windows 11. Everything works well. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 as the second OS. Everything works except the keyboard. No response to key press. External keyboard works. The touchpad works. In GRUB works. How to cure?

Comment: Thinkpad: Win + L locks the computer including the display/screen. Is that maybe what was done?

Comment: WIN+L works on an external keyboard. The laptop keyboard does not respond in any way to pressing.

Comment: If you've installed Ubuntu successfully, then the keyboard workd from LiveUSB. Did it start working after the first reboot after installation?

Comment: after booting from LiveUSB, the keyboard also does not work. It is possible that there are problems with the driver for the USB hub?